# How to split an existing column into three and then append it to the data set?

Tags: r

Good morning, everyone! I am a beginner with R, and I was given an assignment. It looks as follows:

"Split the `“eventdate”` column in the `ACLED` dataset into separate `day`, `month`, and `year` columns that are then appended to the `ACLED` dataset."

We are working with `strsplit()` and `paste()`, but I suspect this is not enough.

The eventdate column in `ACLED` looks like this:

```
"01 August 2020"
```

I was trying to do it like this:

```
strsplit(brazil_acled$event_date, " ")
```

and then use the `paste()` function to append it. But I still do not understand how to create three columns out of splitting text in the existing data set.

I am really new with R and I am with students that are advanced. I am having a difficult time, and I appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Note that I need to do this without using loops.

Comment: Could you please show us the results of str(brazil_acled$event_date)

Comment: I'm not sure how we could use 'paste' for this problem, but see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting the dates gives you a list that you want to `rbind` first before appending to the data frame.

```
S <- strsplit(as.character(ACLED$event_date), " ")
S
# [[1]]
# [1] "18"        "September" "2020"     
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "19"        "September" "2020"     
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "20"        "September" "2020"     
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "21"        "September" "2020"     
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] "22"        "September" "2020"     
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] "23"        "September" "2020"
```

For `rbind`ing multiple elements together we need `do.call(rbind, ...)` and perhaps want to assign appropriate column names.

```
R <- do.call(rbind, S)
colnames(R) <- c("day", "month", "year")
R
#        day  month       year  
# [1,] "18" "September" "2020"
# [2,] "19" "September" "2020"
# [3,] "20" "September" "2020"
# [4,] "21" "September" "2020"
# [5,] "22" "September" "2020"
# [6,] "23" "September" "2020"
```

Finally just `cbind` the result to the original data frame.

```
ACLED <- cbind(ACLED, R)
ACLED
#          event_date    sth_else day     month year
# 1 18 September 2020 -0.78445901  18 September 2020
# 2 19 September 2020 -0.85090759  19 September 2020
# 3 20 September 2020 -2.41420765  20 September 2020
# 4 21 September 2020  0.03612261  21 September 2020
# 5 22 September 2020  0.20599860  22 September 2020
# 6 23 September 2020 -0.36105730  23 September 2020
```

You may also do this in one single step.

```
cbind(ACLED, `colnames<-`(do.call(rbind, strsplit(ACLED$event_date, " ")),
                          c("day", "month", "year")))
```

**Note:**

Maybe you need the splitted date as `"integer"`. In this case you may modify `R` in the following way before `rbind`ing to `ACLED`.

```
R[,2] <- match(R[,2], month.name)  ## using constant built into R
mode(R) <- "integer"
R
#      day month year
# [1,]  18     9 2020
# [2,]  19     9 2020
# [3,]  20     9 2020
# [4,]  21     9 2020
# [5,]  22     9 2020
# [6,]  23     9 2020
```

---

*Example data:*

```
ACLED <- structure(list(event_date = c("18 September 2020", "19 September 2020", 
"20 September 2020", "21 September 2020", "22 September 2020", 
"23 September 2020"), sth_else = c(1.37095844714667, -0.564698171396089, 
0.363128411337339, 0.63286260496104, 0.404268323140999, -0.106124516091484
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry `paste` is of no use here since it sort of the opposite of `strsplit`.  Another possibility that you may find clearer using `strsplit`.

You had the basics correct and you recognized what you needed which was some tool to take the 3 results from `strsplit` and put them in the right columns.

May I suggest `sapply`.  Although not exactly simple you can quickly divine that  `"[", 1` is `r`'s way of saying grab the nth piece

```r
# fake data

brazil_acled <- structure(list(event_date = c("18 September 2020", "19 September 2020", 
                                       "20 September 2020", "21 September 2020", "22 September 2020", 
                                       "23 September 2020")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

brazil_acled

#>          event_date
#> 1 18 September 2020
#> 2 19 September 2020
#> 3 20 September 2020
#> 4 21 September 2020
#> 5 22 September 2020
#> 6 23 September 2020

brazil_acled$day <- sapply(strsplit(brazil_acled$event_date, " "), "[", 1)
brazil_acled$month <- sapply(strsplit(brazil_acled$event_date, " "), "[", 2)
brazil_acled$year <- sapply(strsplit(brazil_acled$event_date, " "), "[", 3)

brazil_acled
#>          event_date day     month year
#> 1 18 September 2020  18 September 2020
#> 2 19 September 2020  19 September 2020
#> 3 20 September 2020  20 September 2020
#> 4 21 September 2020  21 September 2020
#> 5 22 September 2020  22 September 2020
#> 6 23 September 2020  23 September 2020
```

`paste` would be useful to paste them back together in a different order...

```r
brazil_acled$YMD <- paste(brazil_acled$year, brazil_acled$month, brazil_acled$day, sep = "-")
```